# BooleandField can't be False in a Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a form to upload a file, select multiple categories and a BooleanField for mark the file as a proyect or no, the Widget for this Boolean is a Select with choices yes or no. My problem is I can not make save () when BooleanField value is False, i have tried without using the custom Widget, and CheckBox fails too. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

models.py

```
class file(models.Model):
    def url(self,filename):
        ruta = "files/%s/%s"%(self.nombre.str(filename))
        return ruta
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file    = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    status  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.BooleanField()
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(main_category)
    category1   = models.ManyToManyField(category1, related_name='files')
    category2   = models.ManyToManyField(category2, related_name='files')
    def __unicode__(self):
        fileinfo = "%s %s"%(self.name,self.file)
        return fileinfo
```

forms.py

```
choices = ( (1,'Yes'),
            (0,'No'),
          )

class uploadfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width:450px'}),initial="Name")
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style':'width:450px'}),initial="Description for your file")
    file    = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput())
    main_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=main_category.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select())
    category1   = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=category1.objects.all(),widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'style':'width:218px; height:90px'}),required=True)
    category2   = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=category2.objects.all(),widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'style':'width:218px; height:90px'}),required=False)
    project = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.Select(choices=choices))
    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def upload_file_view(request):
    info = "Starting"
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = uploadfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                description = form.cleaned_data['description']
                file = request.FILES['file']
                category1 = form.cleaned_data['category1']
                category2 = form.cleaned_data['category2']
                main_category = form.cleaned_data['main_category']
                project = form.cleaned_data['project']
                user = request.user
                p = file()
                p.user = user
                p.main_category = main_category
                p.save()
                p.name = name
                p.description = description
                p.project = project
                p.file  = file
                p.category1 = category1
                p.category2 = category2
                p.status = True
                p.save()
                info = "File saved"
            else:
                info = "File cant be saved"
        form = uploadfileForm()
        ctx = {'form':form, 'info':info}
        return render_to_response('files/uploadfile.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I'm showing the variable info in my template and when I use the False value for project, can not be saved, and I get the message "File cant be saved".

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `ModelForm`? [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) I'm not sure if it would solve your problem, but it would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I thought ModelForm were used to add special features, I'm documenting now, thanks.
It is wrong to use this type of form, if not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In models you should define boolean fields like `models.BooleanField(blank=True)`. That will however only work in forms when you use `ModelForm`. If you need the same behavior for a regular form, then define the field as `forms.BooleanField(required=False)`.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly now, this required = False was killing me, this is the solution.